Deploy Simple Smart Contract Error: Cannot sign a transaction due to an error while fetching the most recent nonce value
I created and deployed a simple Rust "Hello Contract" example on WSL2 (Windows 11) with testnet account created and login successfully but always get the following error:
Error:
0: Cannot sign a transaction due to an error while fetching the most recent nonce value
1: handler error: [Access key for public key ed25519:ABBukUwJxXfeBrnWD5pXNzFQLeQyuz2pj69N5tZoaucm has never been observed on the node]
Location:
/home/runner/.cargo/registry/src/index.crates.io-6f17d22bba15001f/near-cli-rs-0.11.0/src/transaction_signature_options/sign_with_legacy_keychain/mod.rs:184
Same error on both rpc server: rpc.testnet.near.org   and rpc.testnet.pagoda.co
Someone told me that was the problem sometime and I tried again the next day without any help.
Anybody have same problem?
